# Undefined SELECT query nodejs + jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

SELECT always displays me `undefined` in the input text

[image: Demo]

**Route:**

```
exports.edit = function(req, res){
    var id =(req.params.id);
    customer = db.getCustomerById(id,function(results){
        res.render('customer/edit', {customer: results });
    });
};
```

**DB function:**

```
exports.getCustomerById = function(id,callback){
    var objBD = BD();
    objBD.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=? ', id, callback);
 };
```

**Edit.jade :**

```
form(id='form', method='POST', action='/customer/edit/#{customer.id}')
    input(type='text', id='name', name='name' value='#{customer.name}')
    input(type='email', id='email', name='email' value='#{customer.email}')
    input(type='tel', id='phone', name='telephone' value='#{customer.phone}')
```

Comment: Which module are you using for making database queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback you pass in `db.getCustomerById` should have the format `callback(err, results`). And I guess that `results` argument will be an array and so to pick the customer you will need to do `customer = results[0]`.

Try the following code:

```
exports.edit = function(req, res){
   var id =(req.params.id);
   customer = db.getCustomerById(id,function(err, results){
      if (err) {
        console.log("Ops! Error trying to get customer ....");
        throw err;
      }
      res.render('customer/edit', {customer: results[0] });
   });
};
```